# how to find probability that in 10 families at least 2 of them has a cat?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-distribution

> in a city, probability that a family has a cat is 0.2.
> P(X) = 0.2
> find probability that in 10 families at least 2 of them has a cat.

$P(Y \geq 2) = ? $

I've tried to define a bernoulli distribution with paramenter 0.2. and then generalize it with a binomial distributiom with parameters (10, 0.2). Then, I rewrote $P(Y \geq 2)$ as $1 - P(Y \leq 2)$.

Now, $P(Y \leq 2)$ is equal to two binomial distributions solved for $k = 1$, and $k = 2$.

(for this question it's not important to solve this numerically, but only the logic behind a similar probability problem), I don't think it makes sense, because binomial distribution is discrete not continuous, and therefore I don't think $P(Y \geq 2)$ can be solved this way  because in a discrete case distribution function (i.e $F_y()$) is not defined.

another way I was thinking of is to approximate the binomial distribution with a normal distribution using De Moivre-Laplace theorem. Of course, in order to use this theorem, I need to increase the sample size, otherwise I'd get a bad approximation of the final result.

Comment: In this context the complement of event $\{Y\geq2\}$ is event $\{Y=0\text{ or }Y=1\}$. There are no obstacles to find the probability of this event.

Comment: Don't overthink it. For a given random set of 10 families Pr (no cats) = (0.8)^10. Pr (1 family has a cat) can be worked out fairly similarly. Your answer is 1 minus those two numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer your question. A little suggestion: try to write in Latex.

The sought random variable is a binomial one, with parameters $n=10$ and $p = 0.2 = 1/5$, i.e. $X \sim \text{Bin}(10,1/5)$.

Now,

$$
\text{Pr}\left[X \ge 2\right] = 1 - \text{Pr}\left[X < 2\right] = 1 - \text{Pr}\left[X = 0 \right] - \text{Pr}\left[X  = 1 \right].
$$

In general,

$$
\text{Pr}\left[X = k \right] = {n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n - k}.
$$

Thus,

$$
\text{Pr}\left[X = 0\right]= {10\choose 0}\left({\frac 1 5}\right)^0\left({\frac 4 5}\right)^{10} = \left({\frac 4 5}\right)^{10},
$$

and

$$
\text{Pr}\left[X = 1\right]= {10\choose 1}\left({\frac 1 5}\right)^1\left({\frac 4 5}\right)^{9} = 2\left({\frac 4 5}\right)^{9}.
$$

By plugging these results into the first formula, we get

$$
\text{Pr}\left[X \ge 2\right] = 1 - \left({\frac 4 5}\right)^{10} -2\left({\frac 4 5}\right)^{9} = 1 - \frac{4^{10} + \frac{5}{2}4^{10}}{5^{10}} = 1 - \frac{7}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{10} \approx 0.62
$$